# Why do some apps need to be explicitly allowed on a firewall and others not?

Tags: networking, firewall

This has been so with both the [Windows firewall](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Windows_Firewall#/External_links) and with [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW); hence, the general form of this question.

Why is it that some apps, e.g., web browsers, don't need to be explicitly allowed on (at least the above) firewalls, but other apps, such as those that manage torrents, do need to be so allowed?

It seems I've always been able to download anything, in any way, from any web browser behind a firewall. I don't understand why this traffic has always been allowed, but traffic outside my browsers hasn't. What are the rules at work here?

Thanks

Comment: Programs need firewall access to open a *listening* socket (by default). Applications connecting out to someone else don't need firewall permission (by default).

Comment: Yes, I understand now from the other answer. The confusion arises from the technical use of *listen/receive*. Ordinarily, even if a message is sent out in some realm of discourse, then we wait and listen/receive any responding messages. It seems that in computers this is not the case. The concept of listening/receiving here seems exclusive of this sort of ordinary understanding.

Comment: It's just vernacular/nomenclature specifically adopted and defined by the industry sector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends largely on whether the program needs to *receive* connections.

Web browsers transmit data through the firewall with a unique identifier and the remote server responds back with that same identifier. The firewall allows that data to come back in without issue because the identifiers match. On the outgoing packet a temporary port is opened on the firewall and packets with the correct identifier sent to that same port have a known destination and "trusted" reason to be there.

Bittorrent programs and other servers on the other hand do not send a packet out first, instead they wait on connections from the Internet. Their ports are neither temporary nor are there any unique identifiers exchanged from the bittorrent client to establish whether the traffic is "intentional" and temporary.

As a result for programs expecting incoming connections you have to specifically open ports on the firewall and hold them open.

Comment: Simple and clear explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Of the two above, I am most familiar with Windows (10 and below) firewalls.

The Windows Firewall is highly detailed (hundreds of apps allowed).  This has been done so that ordinary users (most users) do not have to deal with allowing their apps through the firewall. Microsoft staff keep the firewall very up to date, and make decisions about what apps to allow and what not to allow (I am sure there is some consensus in this approach).

Torrents and other like network activity is not only not common with ordinary users but torrents can be dangerous if one downloads the wrong thing. So these are not allowed.

I deal with lots of things and rarely have a Firewall request pop up to allow (Ubiquiti comes to mind).

So I think what you see is normal.

[image: Windows 10 Firewall]